# SQL - Aggregate dates from different columns into Month/Year table

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

So I have an 'Orders' table that lists the 'Ordered' and 'Shipped' dates for each order.
These are custom products and it takes 1 week to fill orders.

This is pretty representative of the table I have:

[image]

I want to aggregate this into a table so that I can see how many orders were ordered and shipped for each month during the date range specified when the report is run, and I want the Months and years to automatically populate without me having to hardcode for each month and year:

[image]

What's the best way to do this with SQL?

I eventually want to place the aggregated table into an SSRS report so that you can expand/collapse each year, if needed.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date/time functions are notoriously database dependent.  Here is a typical approach, though:

```
select yyyy, mm, sum(num_ordered), sum(num_shipped)
from ((select year(ordered) as yyyy, month(ordered) as mm, count(*) as num_ordered, 0 as num_shipped
       from orders
       group by year(ordered), month(ordered)
      ) union all
      (select year(shipped) as yyyy, month(shipped) as mm, 0 count(*) as num_shipped
       from orders
       group by year(shipped), month(shipped)
      ) 
     ) ym
group by yyyy, mm;
```